# 'ip link set' command on multiple interfaces. Using brace expansion for enumerating interfaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell, networking, iproute

I'm trying to set the link up using 'ip link set' command. But I need to type this for each interface as below.

```
ip link set ens1f0 up
ip link set ens1f1 up
ip link set ens1f2 up
ip link set ens1f3 up
```

Is there a way to use brace expansion feature of bash so that this can be done in single command? Something like below

```
"ip link set ens1f"{0..3}" up"
```

I used the echo command to print the commands first and then copied the commands as below. But it is a two step process.

```
$ echo "ip link set ens1f"{0..3}" up;"
ip link set ens1f0 up; ip link set ens1f1 up; ip link set ens1f2 up; ip link set ens1f3 up;
$ ip link set ens1f0 up; ip link set ens1f1 up; ip link set ens1f2 up; ip link set ens1f3 up;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generates a list of interfaces' name with:

```bash
printf 'ens1f%d\n' {0..3}
```

Pipes this stream to `xargs` so it can execute the `ip` command with each interface name:

```bash
printf 'ens1f%d\n' {0..3} | xargs -I{} ip link set "{}" up
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was also trying a few other methods and got the following command to work `eval $(echo "ip link set ens1f"{0..3}" up;")`. Do you see any problems with this approach?

Comment: @ss3071 This approach is risky because `eval` is evil; expanding string into a fully functional shell script (is self modifiable running foreign not audited  code) and inappropriate because it expands arguments on space delimiters.